# How to shorten XSLT select OR conditional?

Tags: conditional-statements, xslt-1.0

I have this XSL code:

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="$orderData[@RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='EXPEDITED']|$orderData[@RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='3DAY']|$orderData[@RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='2DAY']|$orderData[@RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='1DAY']|$orderData[@RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='FDX1DAY']|$orderData[@RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='FDX1DAYI']|$orderData[@RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='FDX2DAYI']|$orderData[@RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='FDX3DAY']">
    <script>console.log("expedited order detected ;)");</script>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I am wondering if there is any way of shortening the conditional statement in the `select`. I have already looked over [XSLT shorter version of OR conditional statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243828/xslt-shorter-version-of-or-conditional-statement), but this does not show how to shorten conditionals in an XSLT `select`.
Can this expression be shortened? If so, how?

I appreciated any feedback!

Comment: Please tag your XSLT version (1.0, 2.0, 3.0)? Also,for 2.0 how does accepted answer in solution not work to shorten your `select`? Place the logic in brackets, `[...]`: `$orderData[@RTSHIPOPTIONCODE = ('EXPEDITED', '3DAY', ...)]`

Comment: I tagged my version(xslt 1.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0 you can do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$orderData[contains('|EXPEDITED|3DAY|2DAY|1DAY|FDX1DAY|FDX1DAYI|FDX2DAYI|FDX3DAY|', concat('|', @RTSHIPOPTIONCODE, '|'))]">
```

Or do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$orderData[@RTSHIPOPTIONCODE = document('')/*/my:allowed-values/value]">
```

after placing this at the top level of your stylesheet:

```
<my:allowed-values>
    <value>EXPEDITED</value>
    <value>3DAY</value>
    <value>2DAY</value>
    <value>1DAY</value>
    <value>FDX1DAY</value>
    <value>FDX1DAYI</value>
    <value>FDX2DAYI</value>
    <value>FDX3DAY</value>
</my:allowed-values>
```

and including:

```
xmlns:my="http://example.com/my"
exclude-result-prefixes="my"
```

in the `xsl:stylesheet` start-tag.

Both of these methods are mentioned in the thread you linked to - I don't know why you couldn't implement them. As you can see, there is nothing special about a "conditional statement".

---

BTW, doing simply:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$orderData[@RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='EXPEDITED' or @RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='3DAY' or @RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='2DAY' or @RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='1DAY' or @RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='FDX1DAY' or @RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='FDX1DAYI' or @RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='FDX2DAYI' or @RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='FDX3DAY']">
```

is not such a bad option either - esp. if you make it more readable by indenting:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$orderData[
    @RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='EXPEDITED' or 
    @RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='3DAY' or 
    @RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='2DAY' or 
    @RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='1DAY' or 
    @RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='FDX1DAY' or 
    @RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='FDX1DAYI' or 
    @RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='FDX2DAYI' or 
    @RTSHIPOPTIONCODE='FDX3DAY'
]">
```

Comment: Thank you! I like these solutions much better than mine ;)
Kudos for showing multiple different ways to do this!